# Python - Remove dicts with empty values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'd like to remove the list of dictionaries elements that have empty values.

So for the following:

```
dict = [{"end": "00:15", "item": "Paul Test 1", "start": "00:00"}, {"end": "00:14", "item": "Paul Test 2 ", "start": "00:30"}, {"end": "", "item": "", "start": ""},  {"end": "", "item": "", "start": ""}, {"end": "", "item": "", "start": ""}]
```

would return a new dict of:

```
[{"end": "00:15", "item": "Paul Test 1", "start": "00:00"}, {"end": "00:14", "item": "Paul Test 2 ", "start": "00:30"}]
```

I've tried:

```
{k:v for k,v in dict if not v}
```

but I'm getting:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
print([d for d in arr if all(d.values())])
```

Don't use `dict` as a name: you override Python's one. And in your case it's not a dictionary, it is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: You should use `d.values()` since the keys are not used.

Comment: Brilliant that's worked thanks. One question though, I thought arrays contained parenthesis and lists contained square brackets?

Comment: ah forgive me, I was getting arrays confused with tuples.